# Class Validator custom

Tags: typescript, boolean, class-validator

Hey guys I have a question about class validator. I've written a custom class validator exists, which checks whether an object with property already exists.
Here is the code

```
@Injectable()
@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
export class ExistsConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private connection: Connection) {
  }

  defaultMessage(validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): string {
    return '';
  }

  validate(value: any, validationArguments?: ValidationArguments): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const entity = validationArguments.constraints[0];
    const isId = validationArguments.constraints[1];
    const property = validationArguments.property;

    const exists = (result) => {
      return !!result;
    };

    const repository: Repository<any> = this.connection.getRepository(entity);
    return isId ? repository.findOne(value).then(exists) : repository.findOne({[property]: value}).then(exists);
  }

}

export function Exists(entity, isObjectId?, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function(object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [entity, isObjectId],
      validator: ExistsConstraint,
    });
  };
}
```

It is useful when I want to grab a user with id, something like this.

```
export class FindByIdParam{
  @IsString()
  @IsMongoId()
  @Exists(User,true)
  id: string;
}
```

But it can also have different usages I think like checking whether the user with such email already registered when trying to create a user.
And that's the question: this validator returns true when entity with property exists, how can I (in some situations) get !validator. I mean it will return true when entity DOES NOT EXIST? Is there a way to achieve this with this validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not such a way, that's why in their documentation they have 2 decorators for every case.

```js
@Equals
@NotEquals
@IsEmpty
@IsNotEmpty
@IsIn
@IsNotIn
```

etc.

What you can do - is to share code base, for example to use this class as a base class for the opposite case and simply invert its result from the super method.